# Set environment variable during build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created an app with Angular-CLI and for debugging purposes would like to show some info in the app about the build that is running. For example, the git branch or build time, etc.

I could write a script that manipulates `src/environments/environment.ts` but I'm asking myself if there is a better way. Especially since that file is part of source control.

A switch on the Angular-CLI to overwrite a variable's value would be nice. Let's say the variables `environment.build` and `environment.time` are set to dummys in `environment.ts`. Then with `ng --env[build]=master --env[time]=201612130742` I'd overwrite those with the computed values.

But to my knowledge something like that doesn't exist?

Comment: i have a also a node script that also writes into environments folder but to a separate file and after that the application reads the file content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config) to inject the config in your CI/CD process. Also, take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e) article for more options on how to implement this.

Comment: This solution only works with Angular 1.x. The real question is for Angular CLI (Angular X).

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli comes with environments out of the box.  if you  already ejected your project with `ng eject` you will need to configure environment files manually

you can pass environment variables to the webpack build for any values you want.  I am using the env variable to pass in the environment and select the environment config file but you can set other variables as shown below

My package.json provides the environment flag during the script build process

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.target=local --port=4200 --history-api-fallback",
"build:prod": "webpack --env.target=prod --env.zip --env.aot --env.extreme --colors",
```

You could use the environment flag

```
// export a function that returns a promise that returns the config object
module.exports = function(env) {
const isAot = env.aot || false;
const isZip = env.zip || false;
const isExtreme = env.extreme || false;
const isAnalyze = env.analyze || false;
const isVirtualbox = env.virtualbox || false;
const isLocal = env.target === 'local';
if(isLocal) { /* set the css file to a variable mycssfile*/ }
```